# How to lauch dotnet.exe in a new command prompt without closing it before I call CloseMainWindow?

Tags: powershell, .net-core, iis-express

I would like to launch a .NET Core Web app in a batch file and then send a client request to it, then close the Web app.

```
cd $PSScriptRoot
$DevWebRootPath=$PSScriptRoot+"\MyWebApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0"
$WebAssembly="MyWebApp.dll"
cd $DevWebRootPath
$processInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("dotnet.exe", $WebAssembly)
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($processInfo)

Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:5000/api/codegen -Method POST -InFile "$($PSScriptRoot)\MyWebApp\Payload.json" -ContentType "application/json"

$process.CloseMainWindow()
cd $PSScriptRoot
```

However, the CMD window hosting the .net core process just disappear right after launching, before Invoke-RestMethod or process.CloseMainMaindow() could run. I had tried similar practices with iisexpress.exe and asp.net Web API, it was working well.

How to lauch dotnet.exe in a new command prompt without closing it before I call CloseMainWindow?

Comment: Try "Start-Process -FilePath 'dotnet.exe' -ArgumentList $WebAssembly" Closing with "(get-process | where { $_.ProcessName -eq 'dotnet.exe' }).CloseMainWindow()"

Comment: @f6a4 For reference, you can wrap your code in grave accent (\`) in order to make it monospaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd avoid manual .NET manipulation where you can and rely on built-in methods (that's the entire point of cmdlets):

```
$path = "$PSScriptRoot\MyWebApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0"
$procArgs = @{
    FilePath         = "$path\dotnet.exe"
    ArgumentList     = "$path\MyWebApp.dll"
    WorkingDirectory = $path
    PassThru         = $true
}
$process = Start-Process @procArgs

$restArgs = @{
    Uri         = 'http://localhost:5000/api/codegen'
    Method      = 'Post'
    InFile      = "$PSScriptRoot\MyWebApp\Payload.json"
    ContentType = 'application/json'
}
Invoke-RestMethod @restArgs

$process.CloseMainWindow() # Should be `$process | Stop-Process`
```

As a default, `Start-Process` opens the window in a new console unless you use `-NoNewWindow`.

Comment: It works after using ArgumentList     = "$path\MyWebApp.dll"

Comment: So your dll is paired with the dotnet executable @ZZZ

Comment: The config that works is FilePath         = "dotnet.exe"
    ArgumentList     = "$path\MyWebApp.dll"  since dotnet.exe is smart enough to see MyWebApp.dll is to be hosted.